# How to en-large the package name field in springboot log

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring and now checking a large code base, so I want to enable detailed logs. Now I got some logs like

```
2023-05-22 13:21:20.504  INFO 76276 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : DatebookHikariCP - Starting...
2023-05-22 13:21:20.716  INFO 76276 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : DatebookHikariCP - Start completed.
2023-05-22 13:21:20.721 DEBUG 76276 --- [           main] c.w.d.S.selectAllProperties              : ==>  Preparing: SELECT SKEY, SDATA FROM SYS_PROPERTY 
2023-05-22 13:21:20.734 DEBUG 76276 --- [           main] c.w.d.S.selectAllProperties              : ==> Parameters
```

From the log, it seems when the package name is large, it will be shortened gracefully. I hope I can configure the maximum allowed length of the field, so that I can see the full name of the package for most cases.
Is there any config item for it? Or any other way for the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your log pattern in logback.xml.
There will be `logger` pattern inside it like `%logger{30}`

 You can specify the length limit in curly braces. If the fully qualified class name is bigger than this length, it will be shortened. Only the last part i.e. classname will not be shortened. 
 If you don't want any limit and always want to print the Fully qualified class name, mention `%logger` without any curly braces. 
 You can check official documentation for more details at [Layout](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord)

Comment: I found my file is logback-spring.xml. These are the lines
class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
<pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
I had hoped to override the %logger value, but didn't succeed. So I just modify the ${FILE_LOG_PATTERN} to "%d %p %c [%t] %m%n"